# HTML5 Video: Unknown MIME type with Content Type application/vnd.apple.mpegurl

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm having some trouble trying to play a video using HTML.
The src is correct, if I run it with VLC, for instance, it shows the video normally. My stream is throwing "**application/vnd.apple.mpegurl**" as **Content Type**.

I've been trying to set many different values for the "type" attribute but none of the ones that I tried work. Watching for the console, in Internet Explorer I see the error message: **MEDIA12899: AUDIO/VIDEO: Unknown MIME type**.

I'm pasting below the HTML. I replaced the real address with some X for safety reasons but I guess the real important info is still there:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Video HTML 5</h1>
    <video width="480" height="300" id="video1" autoplay="autoplay" controls="" poster="poster.jpg">
        <source src="http://example.com:1935/xxx/mp4:xxx.mp4/playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" />
        <script type="text/javascript">alert('Fail!');</script>
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Do you guys have any tip on how to solve the issue? I know the problem is the mime type, but is there something that I'm overlooking, am I fighting a lost battle, something like it?

Answer (score 3):

Use **application/x-mpegURL** and Chrome and Android browser will play it. Android OS must to be > 4.0.

Firefox refuses to play hls if you don't use a hook, but you have open source tools like [video-js](http://videojs.com/) and its [hls plugin](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls) or [hls plugin for videojs5+ by Peer5](https://github.com/peer5/videojs-contrib-hls.js) that you can use to play it on modern browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Internet explorer does not support the HLS streaming format.

Comment: What about Chrome, Firefox and Safari? I've been trying to run in these browsers and the same happens.

Comment: Safari, on ios/mac, Yes. The rest, No.